# Firebase FCM - Why am I getting: payload error, invalid 'android' (or 'apns') property

Tags: node.js, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

I am using cloud functions (node.js) to send notifications to devices. I have my payload set up like this:

```
const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: payloadSender,
        body: payloadMessage,
    },
    data: {
        chatId: chatId,
    },
    android: {
        priority: 'normal',
        collapse_key: chatId,
        //todo how to set badge?
        notification: {
          sound: 'messageSent.wav',  
        },
    },
    apns: {
        headers: {
            'apns-priority': '5',
            'apns-collapse-id': chatId,
        },
        payload: {
            aps: {
                badge: newUnreads,
                sound: 'messageSent.wav',
                'content-available': 1,
            }
        }

    }
};
```

According to the Firebase docs, you can use the "android" and "apns" fields for device specific behavior. Below is the JSON representation [found here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#Notification) for a Message sent by FCM:

```
{
 "name": string,
 "data": {
   string: string,
   ...
},
"notification": {
  object(Notification)
},
"android": {
  object(AndroidConfig)
},
"webpush": {
  object(WebpushConfig)
},
"apns": {
  object(ApnsConfig)
},

// Union field target can be only one of the following:
"token": string,
"topic": string,
"condition": string
// End of list of possible types for union field target.
}
```

Why am I getting the error `Messaging payload contains an invalid "android" property. Valid properties are "data" and "notification".` And `Messaging payload contains an invalid "apns" property. Valid properties are "data" and "notification".`?

Comment: did you find a solution? I am having the same difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell which version you're using based on your post, but it's good to note that the Platform Overrides feature is only available for v1 and *not* Legacy.

Also, I'm not sure if you just removed some items from your sample payload, but there are a lot of unnecessary commas (`,`) in there that's breaking the JSON. Try using an online JSON formatter to double check your payload. I tried one on yours and ended up with this after removing all the errors:

```
{
    "notification": {
        "title": "payloadSender",
        "body": "payloadMessage"
    },
    "data": {
        "chatId": "chatId"
    },
    "android": {
        "priority": "normal",
        "collapse_key": "chatId",
        //todo how to set badge? IIRC, Badges can be enabled via method inside the Android Notification builder
        "notification": {
          "sound": "messageSent.wav"
        }
    },
    "apns": {
        "headers": {
            "apns-priority": "5",
            "apns-collapse-id": "chatId"
        },
        "payload": {
            "aps": {
                "badge": "newUnreads",
                "sound": "messageSent.wav",
                "content-available": 1 // Double check this one if you are to actually use content-available or content_available for FCM
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Just switch out again the variables as needed.

Comment: Just used copy of about JSON.. `Messaging payload contains an invalid "android" property. Valid properties are "data" and "notification`

Comment: @Rajamohan Platform Overrides are only available for v1. I think you're using legacy.

Comment: @AL. Could you please share tell how can I use V1?